# form components disappear in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

[image: NetBeans screen shot]

Very strange occurrence, am in need of a quick way to make my panel components (labels and textboxes) visible again on the form in NetBeans. As soon as I added the Table to the right of the panel, the panel seems to have disappeared. Strangely enough, the components continue to be available in the left side, in the Navigator box, so they are not completely gone, just seem to be hidden. I was unable to find any Visible property, that I could to set to true. Any help is much appreciated. Also, what exactly triggered this behaviour, is this a bug? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Its a focus issue, it makes things easier when you have lots of components.
At the moment you have the scrollPane selected/focused, so you will only be able to see that and any child components.

If you want to see sister or parent components you need to set your focus to your jFrame (or whatever component you want to see).

You can do this from the box on the bottom left, just double click on jFrame, its the top item and also parent to both the scrollPane you have selected now and also parent of your jPanel that contains all the other buttons and labels.

This will have been caused when you double clicked the scrollPane.

Comment: As an aside: you could move your scrollPane inside your jPanel and fix this situation.